# how to make a countdown clock run in the background

Tags: flutter, dart

I am try to create a timer app which have multiple countdown timer for different task. Issue I am facing is that if I start one timer, and press back button, timer stops. So I want, that timer to run till either it is being paused or timer ends and alerts the user or app is destroyed. how can I do this using Flutter?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:slide_countdown_clock/slide_countdown_clock.dart';

class TaskCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  final String info;
  final String buttonText;
  TaskCard({this.buttonText, this.info, this.label});

  @override
  State<TaskCard> createState() => _TaskCardState();
}

class _TaskCardState extends State<TaskCard> {
  bool buttonText = true;
  bool buttonPressed = false;

  buttonTask() {
    if (buttonText == false) {
      return RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: SlideCountdownClock(
            duration: Duration(
              minutes: 2,
            ),
            slideDirection: SlideDirection.Up,
            separator: ":",
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            onDone: () {
              setState(() {
                buttonText = true;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (buttonText == true) {
      return MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            buttonText = false;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          'Get Reward',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink[100]),
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.pink[100],
                  offset: Offset(-2, -1),
                  blurRadius: 5),
            ],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.label,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(widget.info,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                      )),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 0, 90, 0),
                  child: Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                      child: buttonTask()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate singleton(initializes at the start) or global(simpler) object to handle your timer. I assume you are declaring your timers in the widgets which is not a very good place for the stuff that you want to retain the state.

Comment: Hello sir! I hope you are doing fine. Please check the code above. I am new to flutter ,Please help me out.

Comment: waiting for your response sir.

Comment: Sorry fo the late response .
I have setupped this repo that have the globalBloc that will help you understand the global object how they works to keep the state intact even if the screens are destroyed.

Also this repo has the very crude implementation of the countdown you can improve this by using stopwatch that you can pause, restart, stop, resume etc.

https://github.com/Siqlain-Hanif/slider_countdown_example

Comment: thank you sir, I will try to implement this in my application. Thank you very much for your expensive response . Please stay in touch. Thank you again.